# Private Internet Access (PIA) through openvpn?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

After a major upgrade of PIA to Next-Gen, I can no longer connect to PIA servers through openvpn on Ubuntu, and it looks like PIA support has been downgraded to Windows only (they insist I change my DNS to 10.0.0.241 and 10.0.0.243 because it works for them, and I cannot get them to understand this doesn't work for me, as these addresses are on their local network).

Before I give up, is there someone out there who is successfully using the PIA Next-Gen servers through openvpn on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

PIA Customer Support finally admitted this is not working, and not going to work anytime soon.